# Issue when passing `&[&str]` to a method accepting `&'a [T: AsRef<str>]`

Tags: rust

The following sample code works:

```rust
struct Foo<'a, T> {
    foo: &'a [T],
}

impl<'a, T: AsRef<str>> Foo<'a, T> {
    fn f1(foo: &'a [T]) -> Self {
        Self { foo }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo = &["a", "b", "c"];
    let works = Foo { foo };
}
```

while the following sample code does not compile:

```rust
struct Foo<'a, T> {
    foo: &'a [T],
}

impl<'a, T: AsRef<str>> Foo<'a, T> {
    fn f1(foo: &'a [T]) -> Self {
        Self { foo }
    }

    fn f2() -> Self {
        let foo = &["a", "b", "c"];
        Self::f1(foo)
    }
}
```

with error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src\main.rs:12:18
   |
12 |         Self::f1(foo)
   |         -------- ^^^ expected `&[T]`, found `&[&str; 3]`
   |         |
   |         arguments to this function are incorrect
   |
   = note: expected reference `&[T]`
              found reference `&[&str; 3]`
note: associated function defined here
  --> src\main.rs:6:8
   |
6  |     fn f1(foo: &'a [T]) -> Self {
   |        ^^ ------------
```

I kind of understand why, but I'm struggling to understand how to fix it. Shouldn't `&[&str]` be considered like a particular form of `&'a [T: AsRef<str>]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is caused by the use of `Self`. It literally stands for the current type, which in this case is the type declared for the `impl` block, `Foo<'a, T>`. You can *instantiate* `T` with `&str`, but the `f2` function does not work for *any* choice of `T` (which could be chosen at the callsite, for example).

You can fix this by either writing the method in an `impl` block that is not generic over `T`:

```rust
impl<'a> Foo<'a, &str> {
    fn f2() -> Self {
        let foo = &["a", "b", "c"];
        Self::f1(foo)
    }
}
```

Or you can keep the function in the same `impl` block but avoid using `Self`:

```rust
impl<'a, T: AsRef<str>> Foo<'a, T> {
    fn f2() -> Foo<'a, &'a str> {
        let foo = &["a", "b", "c"];
        Foo::f1(foo)
    }
}
```